# How to add class to not clicked radio button in radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a radio button group like below

```
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="8" accessory="14" img="/male/C8A14">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="9" accessory="15" img="/male/C9A15">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="10" accessory="16" img="/male/C10A16">
```

and so on..

I need to add a CSS class to not clicked radio buttons when I click a button using `JQuery`.

Below code not working as expected and it add a class when click.

```js
$('.radiowear').click(function() {
  if ($('input:radio[name=wear_radio]').not(":checked")) {
    $(this).addClass('low-up');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('low-up');
  }
  console.log(this.getAttribute('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="8" accessory="14" img="/male/C8A14">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="9" accessory="15" img="/male/C9A15">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="10" accessory="16" img="/male/C10A16">
```

What is the better way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: is there a reason why you add an extra class to not clicked buttons instead of the other way around? 
and with `this` you are referencing the current element which got clicked, try using the same selector as in the if

Comment: Don't listen for click events on radio; listen for change events.

Comment: Can you please point to a documentation that says `accessory` or `shoe` are  valid HTML5 attributes?

Comment: @rebecca yes its styling purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$(this).addClass('low-up');`, Get the unchecked inputs and add class to them.

```js
$('.radiowear').change(function() {
  const unCheckedInputs = $('input:radio[name=wear_radio]').not(":checked");
  unCheckedInputs.addClass('low-up');
  $(this).removeClass('low-up');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="8" accessory="14" img="/male/C8A14">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="9" accessory="15" img="/male/C9A15">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="10" accessory="16" img="/male/C10A16">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change class on all and remove on this - I had to wrap in a label to see any change to the class. Remove .parent() if you want to change the class on the radio instead

I added a test for checked so I can trigger change onload in case one is already checked

```js
const $wearradios =  $('.radiowear');
$wearradios.on("change",function(e) {
  $wearradios.parent().addClass("low-up");
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("low-up",!this.checked)
}).change();
```

```css
.low-up { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" class="radiowear" 
  name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="8" data-accessory="14" data-img="/male/C8A14"></label>
<label><input type="radio" class="radiowear" 
  name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="9" data-accessory="15" data-img="/male/C9A15"></label>
<label><input type="radio" class="radiowear" 
  name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="10" data-accessory="16" data-img="/male/C10A16"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Stop using invalid HTML5 attributes. Use `data-*` attributes instead.

## Pure CSS solution:

```css
[name="wear_radio"]:not(:checked) {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="8" data-accessory="14" data-img="/male/C8A14">
<input type="radio" name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="9" data-accessory="15" data-img="/male/C9A15">
<input type="radio" name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="10" data-accessory="16" data-img="/male/C10A16">
```

## jQuery solution

- Don't use the `'click'` Event. Did you know you can change a checkbox without the mouse? Use `'change'`
- Use jQuery's `.attr()` or rather `.prop()` with callback

```js
const $wear_radio = $('[name="wear_radio"]');

$wear_radio.on('change', function() { 
  $wear_radio.prop('class', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('low-up', !this.checked)
  });
});
```

```css
.low-up { outline: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="8" data-accessory="14" data-img="/male/C8A14">
<input type="radio" name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="9" data-accessory="15" data-img="/male/C9A15">
<input type="radio" name="wear_radio" data-shoe="" data-cloth="10" data-accessory="16" data-img="/male/C10A16">
```

Comment: Click is triggered when I press space on a radio too

Comment: Liking the CSS version too

Comment: CSS does not do the thing

Comment: @Miuranga well, luckily it does do the thing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't listen for `click` events on radios; if I change it via my keyboard, or other input means, it won't fire. Listen for `change` events instead.

Secondly, you need `.siblings()`:

```
$('.radiowear').on('change', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('low-up').siblings('.radiowear').addClass('low-up');
});
```

Comment: Click is trigger when I use spacebar too

Comment: Interesting. I had always thought it was bad practice to listen for clicks on radios/checkboxes. Are you saying non-mouse interactions trigger click in all circumstances, rendering this advice obsolete?

Comment: It seems to. I always listened for click since in older IEs the change event did not trigger until a blur.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event and `siblings()`

```js
$('.radiowear').change(function() {
  $(this)
    .removeClass('low-up')
    .siblings()
    .addClass('low-up')
});
```

```css
.radiowear:not(.low-up) {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="8" accessory="14" img="/male/C8A14">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="9" accessory="15" img="/male/C9A15">
<input type="radio" class="radiowear" name="wear_radio" shoe="" cloth="10" accessory="16" img="/male/C10A16">
```